# xslt - Using deep-equal on normalized text

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to run the [deep-equal function](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_deep-equal.html) to compare 2 sequences of nodes.
For sequences that I expect to be matched, the only difference would be some carriage returns here and there and an additional `ID` element for one of the sequences.

So for example:

```
<body>
 <section>
   <p>that's a paragraph</p>
   <p @class="p1">that's another paragraph</p>
 </section>
</body>
```

and :

```
<body>
 <section id="1">
   <p id="2">that's a 
 paragraph</p>
   <p @class="p1"  id="3">that's another paragraph</p>
 </section>
</body>
```

For me, that's a match.

Now, [deep-equal](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_deep-equal.html) does not like the carriage return and the id. So I've been trying to modify it to make sure that it's still a match.

Using [remove-attributes-deep](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-attributes-deep.html), I've wrapped deep-equal:

```
 <xsl:function name="functx:deep-similar" as="xs:boolean">
   <xsl:param name="seq1" as="item()*"/>
   <xsl:param name="seq2" as="item()*"/>

   <xsl:variable name="seq1-noId" select="functx:remove-attributes-deep($seq1,'id')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="seq2-noId" select="functx:remove-attributes-deep($seq2,'id')"/>

   <xsl:sequence select="every $i in 1 to max((count($seq1-noId), count($seq2-noId)))
     satisfies deep-equal($seq1-noId[$i], $seq2-noId[$i])"/>    
 </xsl:function>
```

This code is basically the code from [sequence-deep-equal](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_sequence-deep-equal.html) with [remove-attributes-deep](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-attributes-deep.html) on top of it.

Now I would like to tweak it to also normalize the spaces.

How can I normalize the individual text() of each node of a sequence, while preserving the nodes so that I can run deep-equal on them once updated? I would need it to be inside the function itself.

I cannot strip my files, some spaces are crucial to me.

Comment: You should have a look at the [normalize-space](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_normalize-space.html) function

Comment: yes, but it only returns a string. How can I can rebuild a node with the normalized text?

Comment: Why do you have the requirement "I would need it to be inside the function itself"? I would suggest to write some templates with a particular mode that strips the attributes you want to strip and normalizes text nodes as you want (or perhaps attribute values as well) and then you can use apply-templates on your input sequences in that mode and compare the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to define a named mode that performs the transformation (i.e. text value normalization and `id` attribute removal) you want to perform before comparing with `deep-equal`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="t1">
        <body>
            <section>
                <p>that's a paragraph</p>
                <p class="p1">that's another paragraph</p>
            </section>
        </body>     
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="t2">
        <body>
            <section id="1">
                <p id="2">that's a 
                    paragraph</p>
                <p class="p1"  id="3">that's another paragraph</p>
            </section>
        </body>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="nt1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$t1" mode="normalize"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="nt2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$t2" mode="normalize"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="'deep-equal($t1, $t2): ', deep-equal($t1, $t2), '; deep-equal($nt1, $nt2): ', deep-equal($nt1, $nt2)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="normalize">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@id" mode="normalize"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you don't want the identity transformation for all modes you can of course only define it for the named mode, that is replace

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

by

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="normalize">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="normalize"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm still thinking incorrectly in XSLT... Thanks so much (again, and again) what would I do without you :D? Learning a lot!